Is there a simple way of sorting a vector based on 2 others without losing the original index of the elements in C++?
Given an array of elements, I've got two arrays that contain data identifying each element. For example, element number k is identified by the value contained in position k of both of the arrays. These arrays contain int type values and they can represent the weight and value of each element or whatever.
I'm programming a greedy algorithm that picks first the elements with better relation (a/b) in their values. This can be achieved by checking first the elements with the better relation between its respective values in the arrays. To achieve that, I've thought that storing the elements in one array and sorting them by the relation might be the way to go, because the only thing I would need in my greedy algorithm is taking the first, then the second, and so on until there isn't any more left to pick or the limit is exceeded.
Is there an easy way of doing this?
I've got a first implementation that checks both arrays in every iteration of the algorithm and picks up the element with the best relation from the remaining ones, but implementing the upgrade explained above would improve the time complexity of the algorithm because selection would be O(1) instead of O(n), and that's a key thing in this problem.

Create another vector, populate it with the indexes (basically 0 to original_vector.size() - 1), and then sort the index vector instead. The original vector will remain unchanged, and when you need to use the sorted data use the index vector to get the values from the original vector.

An answer that summarizes the index array method.

std::ranges::sort(std::views::zip(vec0,vec1), {}, [](auto x){return std::get<0>(x)/std::get<1>(x);}); indice numbers are lost, but the two vectors vec0 and vec1 are sorted simultaneously.
